# Fedora 16 terminal delay on bad command

Tags: terminal, fedora

Is it possible to get of the (~3s) delay one gets when typing a bad command in Fedora 16? My friend keeps changing the key map but the delay is even more annoying.

Comment: "My friend keeps changing the keymap but the delay is even more annoying." - How is this related to the question?

Comment: If you are talking about bash shell commands, there isn't normally any delay after entering a command that bash doesn't recognise. Can you give an example of a command, an error message and indicate exactly when the delay occurs?

Comment: 'bash: sl: command not found...' Followed by a 3s delay. Seems to be fedora specific.

Comment: Michael K: How is _this_ relevant to the question?

Comment: I has the same problem on EVERY fedora 17 installation I tried (which is like ~30, with like 6 different configuration thought)  and Paul's answer solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely the bash command not found handler.  If you check `/etc/bashrc` or whereever the global bash config file for your distribution is, you should see something like

```
command_not_found_handle() {

   # what to do
}
```

This may be included into bashrc from external source.

You can prevent this behaviour by unsetting the function in your ~/.bashrc (or just commenting out the function in the global script):

```
 unset -f command_not_found_handle
```

Answer (score 1):

In Fedora 16, this extremely annoying feature is enabled by PackageKit.sh. You can disable it, (as root), by renaming the offending script so that it doesn't have a .sh extension. For example:

```
mv /etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh /etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh.disabled
```